# need to avoid firing trigger on perticular api invocation

Tags: apex, trigger, class, session

I have written one trigger which fires on account create and update,but there is one API which creates/update account and if creation/updation is through that API i don't need to fire trigger.
Please suggest how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have a field (Say `origin` type picklist) on respective object(in your case it is Account).

This field would have several values like `created through code` OR `created through API` OR `created manually`  .

And in your trigger you would check for this field. So if the origin of the record is through API you won't perform the operations in the trigger.

Comment: but how to update that field value as this API ,we cannot make any changes in that API class

Comment: @sam You would need to figure out what unique thing this API is doing, for example maybe it is updating some field which only this API updates, on the basis of that you can discover the origin of the record.

Comment: that also we are not sure the field which will update/create.any other solution

Comment: @sam It is really hard to track from your side if you can't change the API code. Maybe you can contact to vendor (Who write the API code) to provide some mechanism.